# same login with different space

Tags: php, mysql

`www.example.com/admin`

`login.php` is under root folder - `example.com`

There are two sorts of users:

- visitors
- admin

Inside `users` table there is a column named `status` with two values - `visitor` and `admin`.

I want to use the same `login.php` for both of them, this way:

- If a `visitor` is recognized (via username and password) its login
  session is valid only for root folder. He cannot go to admin folder.
- If an `admin` is recognized - its login session is valid for both -
  `root` and `admin` folder.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a “permissions” system on my PHP site that runs off a database. Every page starts with `perms_check( “name of permission” )`. If the user account has that permission, it returns true. If they don’t have the permission they get a “denied” message.

Comment: It's really hard to advise on this as it depends on your future plans and other things that make user levels unique to each other. It sounds like you could simply identify users who are admin by their user ID being in an `admin` table. Then make a new function (eg `isUserAdmin($userId)` and that searches the admin table to see if that userId exists. I didn't write this as an answer because I have no idea if this approach will work or fit into your system or design requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=? AND `password`=?;
```

Would be your query. Once you have received the data set the `status` in your session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['status'] = "user_status";
```

---

Now, add a php file in your admin folder containing the following lines,

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['status'] == "visitor"){
    header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" );
    exit;
}
```

`include_once` this php file at the top of all other php files in admin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple method use this...

Add a column status and use the column type to Boolean on login use two queries in if else as if status is == 1 then login as admin and if status == 0 then login as visitor and simply apply this condition where you want to browse as admin or visitor!